# Generated Servlet Configuration web.xml in AppEngine Project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Im curious about the generated servlet configuration in `web.xml` in my app engine project in eclipse. What's the purpose of this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It seems that is needed for Google Cloud Endpoints. Did you enable this option when creating project?

Comment: @PeterKnego, have u used Google Cloud Endpoints?